# how to make 100% height column divider

Tags: css

Ok the basic setup of main content and sidebar and there should be the thin line in between them. Is there a way of making it in pure css?

```
<row>
<div span6>
<div span1 divider>
<div span5>
</row>
```

So that divider would be one thin line and it would have 100% height? I know I can set the height in jquery or just skip it but just wondering...

Comment: Nothing in the related section (at the right) which solves your problem?

Comment: have you tried http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp ?

Comment: Never heard about a `<row>` element. Also, how can a thin line have 100% height? What does that mean?

Comment: Make proper HTML first, what you have right now is not HTML.

Comment: hope it's pseudo-code ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Make the Content 100% height and equal height columns in this layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159026/how-to-make-the-content-100-height-and-equal-height-columns-in-this-layout)

Answer (score 0):

My opinion - if there is not fixed height (of **.row**) for using *border-left* there is only the posibility to use repeating backround image. (Some dots and *repeat-y* in **.row** )

Comment: now its just divs, lazy typo. I mean there's three divs and the one in between should be equal in height to left or right column which ever is the longest

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a resolve for this as well. I needed a solution that I could implement with "column-count" and came up with the following.

I've simply added a background *(1px x 4px, though the height can be as big or small (1px works) as you'd like)* to the container.

My container code (example:)

```
<div class="column-two">

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris bibendum tortor sit amet ultricies ornare. Integer eu interdum augue. Pellentesque quis semper neque. Duis enim nisl, posuere in sollicitudin id, euismod vel neque. Quisque id nisi cursus, laoreet ante ut, faucibus eros. Mauris orci massa, vestibulum at ante a, semper luctus nunc. Phasellus vel nisi condimentum, congue enim et, auctor elit. Vestibulum libero neque, aliquet eget dapibus quis, ullamcorper a orci.</p>

</div>
```

CSS applied to my container:

```
div.column-two {
-moz-column-count: 2;
-moz-column-gap: 30px;
-webkit-column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-gap: 30px;
background:url('images/div-2column.png') center top repeat-y;
}
```

This creates the 2 column display with the background image creating a visual vertical divide. Does the trick for me! :)

The code

*(I've also added the following, to ensure equal height columns. The following removes the padding from the initial paragraph)*

```
div.column-two p:first-of-type { margin-top:0; }
```

*Note that older IE browsers will fall back to a single column display. Targeting these specific browsers with a "background:none" will ensure the background doesn't display in the middle of your single column paragraph.*