# Full height columns without scroll

Tags: css

I'm working on this site at the moment: http://weloveprivacy.com/ where I'm trying to make the content (#container) stretch to fit from the top (.top-wrap) to the footer (.footer), without getting unnecessary scroll. I want the columns (.front1, .front2, .front3) to always have an equal height and fill out the screen, so the borders stretch from the top to the footer.

Is this possible with pure CSS?

Comment: Can you please add the just the pertinent code into this question so that it will be useful to folks in the future who may have the same problem?

Comment: It looks like @Jawad posted the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9159026/422184) for you after [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9119726/422184). My solution there should work for you as well (seeing as how it is actually the same question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that was fun. Add the following CSS:

```
.nav {
 left:0;
}
#wrapper {
 overflow:hidden;
}
#container {
 height:auto !important;
 min-height:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0;
}
#container > div {
 margin-bottom:-10000px;
 padding-bottom:10000px;
}
.footer {
 margin-top:-97px;
 position:relative;
}
```

View the [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/p9Zvk/1/) to see it in action.

***Note:** The `margin-bottom`/`padding-bottom` hack will break older versions of IE. I'd suggest using conditional statements to provide that style to versions that break, and simply let them see it without the columns stretching down.*

Comment: Thank you! Awesome that it could be done with CSS! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css properties to #container:

```
float: left;
width: 100%;
```

Add the following properties to .front1, .front2, .front 3:

```
width: 33%;
```

Remove width: 318px from front1, front2, front 3. Now the columns will stretch to the entire width of the screen, and each column will be of equal width(occupying 33% of the total width).

Comment: Thank you, but what I want is not full width, but full height :)

Comment: But it is already full height in the site you have given- it stretches fully from topwrap to footer- what exactly r u looking at?

Comment: Must be because you have a small screen resolution, I have removed the images from the columns now, so you should be able to see that it does not stretch

Comment: Ok you can do this: use min-height: 415px; on front1, front2, and front3. So, this ensures that the column height is atleast 415px, irrespective of the content inside.

Comment: I hope this is what your question was

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do isn't possible with pure CSS at least in the way that you're thinking. What you can do, though, is fake it with something like [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/). The idea is that you wrap your three columns with a containing element, then apply a background image to that element that tiles vertically. This can create the illusion of equal height columns.

It's a bit of pain to maintain, as you need to edit an image to make changes, but it is reliable.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Yea faux columns will not work, because I want to use borders. I must try to achieve it with java script :)