# Have footer stretch in height to fill viewport without javascript

Tags: html, css

I have a basic layout where I'd like the footer to take up remaining portion of the viewport after the content. Right now when I use the code below it draws a scrollbar because the height is being calculated as footer height (100%) plus content height (varies), is there a way to prevent the scrollbar without calculating the height of the content with javascript?

```
html,body{height:100%;} 
.content {position: relative;}
.footer{height: 100%; min-height:100%; background-color:green; overflow: hidden;  padding-bottom: -2000px;}

<div class="content">
content
</div>

<div class="footer">
Footer
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160159/full-height-columns-without-scroll. Should be a pretty similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html><head>
<style type="text/css">

body{overflow:hidden;} 
.content {position: relative;}
.footer{height: 100%; background-color:green;  padding-bottom:-2px;margin:0px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>


<div class="content">
content
</div>

<div class="footer">
Footer
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's only for presentational purposes, I would do something like this:

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="content">
    Your main page content here
    </div><!-- #content -->
Your footer content here
</div><!-- #wrap -->
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background: #F0F0F0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#wrap {
    height: 100%;
    width: 800px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: auto;
} 

#content {
    background: #fff;
}
```